# repaint() method causes a second, non-functional JMenuBar to appear?

Tags: java, swing, repaint, jmenubar

I am creating a program in which the user can draw lines and erase them.  I am able to create my window and create a functioning JMenuBar.  When the drawing capability is not enabled, everything is fine. But when the drawing capability is enabled, a second JMenuBar is painted below the original.  This menu bar is not functional, and *sometimes* when it is drawn, ALL of the graphics on the screen are repainted lower as well.  Re-sizing the window in any way remedies these problem.

*I would post pictures but, you know, I'm a new user and can't.*

I have been able to narrow the problem down to a point in my paint() method. Need to know: When the mouse is dragged, the repaint() method is called.  It uses my paint() method which calls the paintObject(Graphics g) method in my Line class.  The JMenuBar error is appearing at the END of the paint method in the top class.

```
public void paint(Graphics g)//paint() in the top class
{            
    for(int i = 0; i < objs.size(); i++)//Loop that finds all Tool(Line) objects that
        ((Tools)objs.get(i)).paintObject(g);//have been drawn, and redraws them.
    //This part of the code completes successfully with no error.

}//ERROR OCCURS HERE!!!!!!
```

I have no idea why this is happening.  As a side note, there is also a JTextField on the screen that doesn't appear until it is highlighted. Thanks for at least reading this far!

Comment: You need to tell more, a lot more. For all we know you may be doing something terribly wrong like drawing directly in the top level window such as a JFrame or JApplet. I'll assume that you're not doing this that you're drawing correctly in a JPanel or JComponent, and if so, draw in the paintComponent method not paint. Also you'll want to post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) so we can test your code better.

Comment: please post a screenshot

Comment: also noticed, you should call super.paint(g)

Comment: @mishanesterenko: he shouldn't even be drawing in the `paint` method.

Answer (score 2):

Edit: I'll go on a limb, I'll bet you in fact are drawing directly on the top level window (JFrame or JApplet or JDialog...) and have added the mouse listener to this window as well -- hence the drawing of components translated down a bit.

The solution is to look at the tutorials first before attempting something fairly complex like this. They'll tell you how to draw correctly including the suggestions I've given in my comments, such as drawing in a JComponent or JPanel's `paintComponent` method and calling the super.paintComponent(g) method as the first method call of your paintComponent override.

Comment: Hey, look at that! the paintComponent() method fixed the problem (My use of the paint() method was simply confusion with all of the API's I was reading.  I failed to recognize it as different in the tutorial)! Thanks!  Just to clarify, I was drawing on JPanel.

This also fixed the problem of the text box not showing up.  Thanks again!

Comment: @user1161539: Glad you've got it working, but that's strange, as I don't know how the JMenuBar could be caught up in a JPanel's paint method. Did you add the JMenuBar to the JFrame via the `setJMenuBar(...)` method? Or was it added to the JPanel?

Comment: UPDATE: I tested the unfixed version on another computer (same OS, same compiler) and the problem wasn't there.

Comment: And to answer your question: Yes, I added it to the frame via the setJMenuBar(...) method.